# Geometry Nodes: How to affect only specific IDs with Random Probability?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Didn't find any matching article here.

So, I have these vertices with IDs (the numbers in the image are just a visualization of those IDs):

[image]

How can I use Random Probability (the boolean one) to affect only the IDs in the middle, or the IDs 10-19? I would like to delete some of those randomly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

just compare the ids and use math bool and to combine it.

Comment: But of course, this makes so much Logical ;) sense! Thank you! I just didn't know the order in which to arrange the boolean math nodes.